# How to create Id on hibernate entity that is a byte[] that maps to a varbinary value in mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, orm, jpa, primary-key

I am trying to create an Entity that has a byte[12] id in hibernate.  It seems like it does not like to have a byte[] as a primary key and as another column it sets it up as a tinyblob in the backing mysql db.  I have tried to create a String, but the problem is that the string in java is 2 bytes per char, while it is one byte per char in mysql.  I'm looking for something like this

```
@Entity
public class TestClass {
    @Id
    @Column(length=12)
    private byte[] id;
...
```

to map to a mysql table like this

```
Table 'testclass'
   Column id - varbinary     length 12     primary key
    ...
```

I have tried a number of different ways (primarily trying to fiddle with Strings) to do this but it does not seem to work right.  Has anyone been able to do this already?  Thanks.

Comment: So we have a 'kind-of' solution that works.  We created a custom UserType with a sqlTypes() return value of Types.VARBINARY.  The only problem is schema creation.  There doesn't seem to be a way to map from a Hibernate.BINARY.sqlType() to a MySQL BINARY or VARBINARY data column.  Hibernate (or the MySQL driver) always seem to want to create a tinyblob for a binary.  Is there any way to say, 'no, create a BINARY type on the db'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you experienced, this is not supported by standard JPA. From the specification:

> #### 2.1.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity
>
> ...
>
> The primary key (or field or property
> of a composite primary key) should be
> one of the following types: any Java
> primitive type; any primitive wrapper
> type; `java.lang.String`;
> `java.util.Date`; `java.sql.Date`. In
> general, however, approximate numeric
> types (e.g., floating point types)
> should never be used in primary keys.
> Entities whose primary keys use types
> other than these will not be portable.
> If generated primary keys are
> used, only integral types will be
> portable. If `java.util.Date` is used as
> a primary key field or property, the
> temporal type should be specified as
> `DATE`.

That being said, it appears that you could use a wrapper type around the `byte[]` and implement a custom user type. The [UserType for a byte[] identifier property](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-13991) wiki page provides an implementation.

Refer to the section [2.4.3.2. Type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2794) of the Hibernate Annotations documentation to declare and use this custom type with annotations.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification
- Section 2.1.4 "Primary Keys and Entity Identity"
- Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide
- [2.4.3.2. Type](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2794)

#### Resource

- JBoss Community Wiki
- [UserType for a byte[] identifier property](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-13991)

Comment: Ya, I realize this, but my code snippet was intended to show what I'm trying to accomplish.  I know it doesn't work, I posted here because I'm trying to find away to do essentially what I illustrated but in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

`byte[]` is not supported as primary key for a reason - using a `BLOB` field for a primary key isn't a good idea (mysql will have to index blobs, I'm not sure this will have good performance). I'm not even sure mysql allows blob keys. There is an error that says BLOB/TEXT can't be used in key specifications.

What you can use is:

- `UUID` - it is 128 bit unique identifier
- Base64 - (using [commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)) encode your byte array to base64 and use a string primary key.

Comment: Ya, I realize I don't want a BLOB as a pk.  What I want in the db is a BINARY(12).  The problem is a long would only give me 8 bytes.  What I've begun to experiment with now is a customer UserType on the field that will directly translate BINARY(12) on the db to byte[] on the entity.